# cURL referer header not being set when requested page

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to set the http_referer using curl using this code:

```
$header[] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/json,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";

$referer = 'www.domain.com';
$url = './test.php';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl-PL; rv:1.9.0.2) Gecko/2008092313 Ubuntu/9.25 (jaunty) Firefox/3.8');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

$data = curl_exec($curl);
```

and the test.php code is just

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

I am able to retrieve the contents of the page, i.e I can see all the $_SERVER variables, but HTTP_REFERER is not being set.

I even tried with `http_x_forwarded_with`, but none of these headers are set.

I only get

```
[HTTP_HOST] => localhost
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,deflate,sdch
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET] => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried you example and it works for me

Comment: on localhost u did ? or on a server ? , im running xampp btw

Comment: I used localhost for testing. One problem I see: `$url='./test.php';` This will not work. Use `$url='http://localhost/test.php';`

Comment: well still not working for me , i dont understand how this is happening , can u give me the code u have now and what are u running to use localhost ?

Comment: well tested something now , seems that none of the headers i pass in my script are being passed out . this is irritating :(

Comment: This is the code that I have : http://pastebin.com/qcvnyeGc .. `test.php` is just `print_r($_SERVER);`

Comment: still not working i think , now its not showing any data at all :(